# Can it be done?

Tags: google-maps

Any opinion? Are these cases not possible?
a) Color points for gmap cities red
b) Color borders between countries yellow
c) Color the text for oceans purple

Comment: You should give a more descriptive title to your post. This doesn't help people understand your problem, thus lessens your chances of getting help.

Comment: I think the docs are quite clear on what can and can't be done... take a look at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeStyleFeatureType

Comment: Thanks for replying. I could implement b) and c) hoping to manage a) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Google Maps API Styled Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)?